# usb stopped working after making it a bootable device

Tags: boot, partitioning, usb, hard-drive

My usb is not being detected after making it a ubuntu bootable device..
the second time when I tried to install it on my hard, disk my hard disk stopped working. The hard disks light turns up but its not being recognised by my current windows PC. I don't know whether the problem is with ubuntu or my hard disk. but it damaged two of my storage devices. Now neither of the usb stick nor the hard disk are recognised by my PC.

Answer (score 0):

You could try overwriting the MBR of the pendrive, with:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/YOUR_DISK bs=512 count=1
```

You can check the device of YOUR_DISK with *sudo fdisk -l*.

Notice that with this, you will lose the contents of the pendrive, but it should be detected again after that. You will have to format it again afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

The file system of Ubuntu is not recognized by Windows. There are applications out there that will allow you to mount the Ext4 file system. Do NOT overwrite the MBR as that will prevent you from booting into Ubuntu.

EDIT: 
Here is a helpful link from HowToGeek that will give you 3 applications to mount the drives, but you can only use them as read-only (writing is risky)
http://www.howtogeek.com/112888/3-ways-to-access-your-linux-partitions-from-windows/